# How to apply pipe zenity/yad progress bar?

Tags: zenity

I need to display a progress bar with zenity or yad with pacaur/pacman or yaourt in Arch Linux/Manjaro.

The problem is that I can't capture the actual process with [pacaur](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacaur) or other, only with [pkcon](http://www.justmanpage.com/man/pkcon.1), but packagekit failed with Arch Linux.  This is my actual line with pacaur but doesn't work.

```
pacaur -S clementine >> /tmp/pacaur-url-tmp |
  tail --lines=1 /tmp/pacaur-url-tmp |
  yad --progress \
    --title="MyProgram - Installing ffdiaporama" \
    --width=300 \
    --height=200 \
    --text="A test my friend" \
    --pulsate \
    --auto-close \
    --button="Cancel (Not recommended):0"
```

Other problem, it ever ask when needs password root, I can't capture it also with zenity/yad...

This is the [result with packagekit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVJUS.png), yes is a simple gui installer and works in all distributions but Arch Linux doesn't work with packagekit.

You can see the output with pacaour [Here](http://pastebin.com/nm9F9dwD).

Comment: Please give an example of the `pacaur` output so that non-Arch users can have an idea of what you are trying to process. Also please give more detail on what you expect to get with `yad`

Comment: Ok :) , http://i60.tinypic.com/30usb34.png

Comment: Your not going to get anything as detailed that, this code will give you a progress bar and that's it. If you post an example of the text output from `pacaur`, I can suggest a fix for this.

Comment: @Graeme Ok, thanks. check my pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nm9F9dwD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, I have tested it on the output you posted. Note that I have used `zenity` since `yad` isn't in the Debian repositories. Also this is `bash` only.

```
(
  exec {fd}>&1
  stdbuf -oL pacaur -S clementine |
    stdbuf -oL tee /dev/fd/$fd |
    stdbuf -oL sed -n '/\.\.\.$/ s/^/# /p' |
    zenity --progress --title="pacaur progress" --pulsate \
      --width=450 --auto-close
)
```

One thing that might go wrong is that `pacaur` might print progress data to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, in which case the second line will probably need to be:

```
 stdbuf -eL -oL pacaur -S clementine 2>&1 |
```

I have added the `exec {fd}>&1` and `tee /dev/fd/$fd` lines so that output will also be printed to the terminal. Without this this script will simply be:

```
  stdbuf -oL pacaur -S clementine |
    stdbuf -oL sed -n '/\.\.\.$/ s/^/# /p' |
    zenity --progress --title="pacaur progress" --pulsate \
      --width=450 --auto-close
```

Btw in my opinion the terminal is the best place to look for the installation progress, but since you asked, `zenity` is a nice thing to play with.

Comment: Yad is in Ubuntu 16.04 now: `sudo apt install yad`.