# Pipe doesn't read my forked script

Tags: pipe

I have a problem. I  modified a script called '[packer](https://github.com/keenerd/packer)' a [AUR-helper](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_Helpers) for [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).  The problem coming when I apply my [pipe](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html), with a progress bar, doesn't show all info as I need.

This is my [forked script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kuboosoft/packer/master/packer-postinstallerf) from packer, the next line install a program from AUR

```
echo > /tmp/packer-url-tmp

packer-postinstallerf -S --noconfirm --noedit alchemy 
   tee /tmp/packer-url-tmp |
   stdbuf -oL sed '/\.\.\.$/ s/^/#/p' |
   zenity --progress --title="packer progress" --pulsate --width=450 --auto-close
```

The output without a pipe and progress bar:

http://pastebin.com/m0srNWkJ

The above line, work fine without AUR packages; but when I install a [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) program disappears the previous information (build process) to  installation.

I do not understand the pipe with the progress bar should show this information.

Only show the pipe with

```
:: ¿Continuar con la instalación? [S/n]
(1/1) verificando llaves en el llavero             [######################] 100%
(1/1) verificando la integridad de los paquetes    [######################] 100%
(1/1) cargando los archivos del paquete...         [######################] 100%
(1/1) verificando conflictos entre archivos        [######################] 100%
(1/1) verificando el espacio disponible en disco   [######################] 100%
(1/1) instalando alchemy                           [######################] 100%
Dependencias opcionales para alchemy
    jpen: for tablet support
```

Please if my question isn't clear, I updated my question. I do not know how to clarify my question more :/.

Comment: Please give an example of the `packer-postinstallerf` output so that non-Arch users can have an idea of what you are trying to process. Also please give more detail on what you expect to get with `zenity`.

Comment: I the above comment sounds familiar to you, it is because I copied it from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120252/how-to-apply-pipe-zenity-yad-progress-bar#comment189270_120252). If you want people to help you with this kind of thing, you have to, at a *minimum*, provide information about that the input is and what you expect the output tob e.

Comment: Hi @Graeme is very strange because the pipe only capture in the installer section ":: ¿Continuar con la instalación? [S/n] ". http://pastebin.com/m0srNWkJ

Comment: Hi the solution was simple: 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/packer-url-tmp | stdbuf -oL sed -nru '/==>/ s/^/# /p'  Although I explained my question with apples, was closed haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because it outputs text both on stderr and stdout, and what you want to capture is on stderr ? I think you lack a pipe here

```
packer-postinstallerf -S --noconfirm --noedit alchemy | ...
```

And try to redirect stderr to stdout before the pipe:

```
packer-postinstallerf -S --noconfirm --noedit alchemy 2>&1 | ...
```

Sorry for the previous link only answer, the reference is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497317/piping-both-stdout-and-stderr-in-bash